# Populating UITableView with rows of SQLite database in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

I'm trying to convince my app of iterating through a SQLite database stored locally on the phone and then populating the cells with the results. The query is done by using SQLite.swift

I thought of iterating through the cells with indexPath.row and the LIMIT option of SQL, but I don't know whether my approach is correct.

My code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCells") as! SettingTableViewCell

    do {
        let query = fatherTable.limit(indexPath.row, offset: indexPath.row)
        for father in try self.localDatabase.prepare(query) {
            cell.label1.text = father[self.fatherName]
            cell.label2.text = father[self.fatherLastName]
            cell.label3.text = father[self.fatherAge]
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do not perform the query in `cellForRowAt`. You need to load the data outside of any data source or delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't correct , you need to fetch all items inside `viewDidLoad` , then reload the table ( if you will do this asynchronously ) , fetching inside `cellForRowAt` is wrong for performance , plus it will set the cell for the last item as `cellForRowAt` is called for each cell

Comment: Ah, that's why the cells were only using the last database entry. So after fetching all items in viewDidLoad, how do I cache them for filling the cells later? An array doesn't seem to work with several columns.

Comment: you need a datasource array